# Periodogram for irregularly spaced data

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to replicate some existing work on the length of the cycles in certain economic data. Specificially, I am using the [Schularick and Taylor (2012) data set](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles.php?doi=10.1257/aer.102.2.1029) to replicate the periodogram shown in [Aikman et al (forthcoming)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecoj.12113/abstract).

[image]

I'm quite unfamiliar with spectral analysis, but I don't seem to be able to replicate the "two-hump" shape of these data.

I'm importing the Stata .dta format data using the technique suggested [over here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/256784):

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
REvaluate["library('foreign')"];

Shallow[rf = REvaluate["read.dta('H:/Work-Research/panel17.dta')"]]
```

The headers are in the first part of the `RData` object. Notice that the level of loans and the CPI are included, not real loans or their growth rate, so I've had to calculate that.

```
rf[[1]]

(* RNames["year", "iso", "rgdpbarro", "rgdp", "loans1", "bassets2", \
"govass", "narrowm", "money", "gdp", "iy", "cpi", "pop", "stir", \
"ltrate", "crisisST", "stocks"] *)
```

The actual data are in the second part.

This is probably over-convoluted, but here is how I'm calculating real loan growth from this data set, while handling `Missing[]` values.

```
realloangrowth[iso_String] := 
 With[{realloanlevel = ({#1, #2/#3}) & @@@ 
      Pick[Transpose[List @@ (rf[[2, {1, 5, 12}]])], rf[[2, 2]], 
       iso] /. (a_?NumericQ Missing[] -> Missing[])}, 
  DeleteCases[   Cases[MapThread[{{#2[[
         1]]}, ((#2[[2]]/#1[[2]])^(1/(#2[[1]] - #1[[1]])))*100 - 100} &, 
 {Most[realloanlevel], Rest[realloanlevel]}] , {_, _?NumericQ}], {_, 0}]]
```

Here's a `DateListPlot` of the real loan growth data.

[image]

Here's the `Periodogram` of those data. As you can see, it looks nothing like the version published in the journal.

```
 Periodogram[realloangrowth["GBR"][[All, 2]], 35, 1, ParzenWindow, 
   PlotLabel -> "Great Britain", ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I tried playing around with different smoothing functions and window sizes (`Manipulate` makes this easy), but the basic shape stayed the same.

One issue that occurs to me is that there is a big gap in the data around World War 2. I'm handling this correctly in the calculation of the growth rates, but does it matter for the calculation of the periodogram?

There are [techniques for handling irregularly spaced data in Fourier transforms](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data), but how might I deal with this in Mathematica? Does it mean I can't use the `Periodogram` function directly?

**EDIT**

For those having trouble with `RLink`, here's the data

```
{{{1881}, 3.56417}, {{1882}, 10.0868}, {{1883}, -1.19687}, {{1884}, 
  12.1664}, {{1885}, 3.89628}, {{1886}, 3.78198}, {{1887}, 
  3.97404}, {{1888}, 3.708}, {{1889}, 3.85748}, {{1890}, 
  2.62319}, {{1891}, 18.2038}, {{1892}, -1.97415}, {{1893}, 
  3.53427}, {{1894}, 4.15533}, {{1895}, 9.35782}, {{1896}, 
  6.54358}, {{1897}, 0.922959}, {{1898}, 0.0553147}, {{1899}, 
  7.66182}, {{1900}, -2.6952}, {{1901}, -1.79063}, {{1902}, \
-0.112891}, {{1903}, 
  1.60311}, {{1904}, -2.1118}, {{1905}, -0.577774}, {{1906}, 
  3.9191}, {{1907}, -0.339656}, {{1908}, -0.897167}, {{1909}, \
-0.043076}, {{1910}, 5.92408}, {{1911}, -0.44858}, {{1912}, 
  0.847448}, {{1913}, 1.83518}, {{1914}, 
  4.20869}, {{1915}, -23.206}, {{1916}, -16.6978}, {{1917}, \
-1.35873}, {{1918}, -11.3358}, {{1919}, 
  55.3335}, {{1920}, -8.61661}, {{1921}, -2.30011}, {{1922}, 
  17.5548}, {{1923}, 8.9448}, {{1924}, 5.62972}, {{1925}, 
  5.16281}, {{1926}, 6.71636}, {{1927}, 4.53271}, {{1928}, 
  3.79909}, {{1929}, 3.23482}, {{1930}, -4.42037}, {{1931}, 
  1.82296}, {{1932}, -11.2975}, {{1933}, -1.87891}, {{1934}, 
  3.27432}, {{1935}, 0.990526}, {{1936}, 5.20246}, {{1937}, 
  4.76605}, {{1938}, -0.839203}, {{1939}, -1.59364}, {{1947}, 
  16.2828}, {{1948}, 4.44382}, {{1949}, 8.89674}, {{1950}, 
  6.20378}, {{1951}, 
  4.69021}, {{1952}, -15.4352}, {{1953}, -5.04831}, {{1954}, 
  8.74151}, {{1955}, -5.13964}, {{1956}, 
  0.932322}, {{1957}, -4.43559}, {{1958}, 14.8821}, {{1959}, 
  30.7378}, {{1960}, 15.7541}, {{1961}, -2.15863}, {{1962}, 
  4.61325}, {{1963}, 14.1566}, {{1964}, 13.2822}, {{1965}, 
  4.97081}, {{1966}, 4.79818}, {{1967}, 8.78431}, {{1968}, 
  6.97021}, {{1969}, 4.75578}, {{1970}, 6.02862}, {{1971}, 
  4.8221}, {{1972}, 19.3864}, {{1973}, 
  14.8845}, {{1974}, -0.943752}, {{1975}, -11.3757}, {{1976}, 
  0.24681}, {{1977}, -1.06783}, {{1978}, 6.56043}, {{1979}, 
  4.01699}, {{1980}, -0.441238}, {{1981}, 3.23678}, {{1982}, 
  11.7512}, {{1983}, 9.66257}, {{1984}, 12.2045}, {{1985}, 
  9.6017}, {{1986}, 13.921}, {{1987}, 12.9436}, {{1988}, 
  18.8436}, {{1989}, 12.098}, {{1990}, 3.25403}, {{1991}, 
  0.0359383}, {{1992}, 0.312743}, {{1993}, 0.883408}, {{1994}, 
  1.77945}, {{1995}, 4.30416}, {{1996}, 6.3142}, {{1997}, 
  3.83672}, {{1998}, 5.61743}, {{1999}, 6.83541}, {{2000}, 
  9.41474}, {{2001}, 8.83823}, {{2002}, 10.3133}, {{2003}, 
  10.4406}, {{2004}, 9.52844}, {{2005}, 9.59797}, {{2006}, 
  9.41623}, {{2007}, 8.53704}, {{2008}, 0.994046}}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am having lunch and reading. I missed that you were already using the Parzen window. The stuff near -->0 is the non periodic signal so they may have trimmed that in some way prior to applying the filter. Unfortunately if you have a one step process rather than two (FT then filter) it might not be as easy to do

Comment: One can apply a `LowpassFilter` to the data before drawing the `Periodogram`, but given that their whole thesis is about the relative importance of other bits of the spectrum, that's a bit odd.

Comment: Notwithstanding the differences in smoothing it looks possible that they have rescaled the x axis by removing the non periodic component. If you started your plot range at 0.1 (or whatever the appropriate point is if you can view the raw FT data), and relabel it to zero and tried different Parzen parameters I suspect you will be able to reproduce this.

Comment: BTW for the irregularly spaced stuff you may want to investigate `TemporalData` and some answers posted by @AndyRoss who I think is the developer.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - unfortunately `Periodogram` doesn't take `TemporalData` in v9, and I don't think that's changed in v10.

Comment: Would it be of much trouble if you share the data set in a different format - I have been having issues with my `RLink` for the past week and can't get it to work.

Comment: @Verbeia you should definitely file a suggestion with WRI for `Periodogram` to take `TemporalData` (and `TimeSeries`). This was on my todo list before I left I just didn't get to it.

Comment: @Verbeia Thank you :) !

Comment: @Sektor - I've pasted the data in for the UK at least.